# Typescript Generics and creating new instances

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this code:

```
export class JsonSerializable {
    toJson(): any {
        const jsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
        jsonConvert.valueCheckingMode = ValueCheckingMode.ALLOW_NULL;
        return jsonConvert.serialize(this);
    }

    static fromJson<T extends JsonSerializable>(data: any): T {
        const jsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
        jsonConvert.valueCheckingMode = ValueCheckingMode.ALLOW_NULL;

        return jsonConvert.deserializeObject(data, T) as T;
    }
}
```

deserializeObject() is defined as:

```
deserializeObject<T>(jsonObject: any, classReference: {
        new (): T;
    }): T;
```

I don't quite understand how I can declare my class to accept this without getting the "**'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here**" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your clue is in the definition of `deserializeObject`. You can't use a type in an expression. Types are erased after compilation `T` will not exist at runtime. That is why `deserializeObject` has a second parameter that takes in the class as a constructor signature (the `classReference` parameter).

You can do the same, and take the class as an extra parameter:

```
export class JsonSerializable {
    toJson(): any {
        const jsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
        jsonConvert.valueCheckingMode = ValueCheckingMode.ALLOW_NULL;
        return jsonConvert.serialize(this);
    }

    static fromJson<T extends JsonSerializable>(data: any, classReference: {
        new (): T;
    }): T {
        const jsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
        jsonConvert.valueCheckingMode = ValueCheckingMode.ALLOW_NULL;

        return jsonConvert.deserializeObject(data, classReference);
    }
}

class MyClass extends JsonSerializable {
    public f = ""
}

let a = JsonSerializable.fromJson({}, MyClass); // a is MyClass
```

Or if you don't mind invoking `fromJson` on the class that you want deserialize, you can use `this` (with an appropriate type annotation on for the `this` parameter):

```
export class JsonSerializable {
    toJson(): any {
        const jsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
        jsonConvert.valueCheckingMode = ValueCheckingMode.ALLOW_NULL;
        return jsonConvert.serialize(this);
    }

    static fromJson<T extends JsonSerializable>(this: new () => T, data: any): T {
        const jsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
        jsonConvert.valueCheckingMode = ValueCheckingMode.ALLOW_NULL;

        return jsonConvert.deserializeObject(data, this);
    }
}

class MyClass extends JsonSerializable {
    public f = ""
}

let a = MyClass.fromJson({}); // a is MyClass
```

Comment: Amazing! I had no idea you could use "this" in a static method like that.